# Unable to select QnA service in the Create Knowledge Base wizard

Tags: azure, azure-qna-maker

I'm using the QnA Maker service for the first time and I went to Create a knowledge base.

In step 1, Create a QnA service in Microsoft Azure, I created an Azure QnA service. This created successfully.

In Step 2, Connect your QnA service to your KB, I select my Azure Directory, my Azure Subscription, and then I can see the QnA service in the dropdown menu, but it is greyed out and I can't select it. No idea why I can't select it and I can't find anything relevant from internet searches. I've deleted and recreated the QnA service a few times.
[Greyed out QnA Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvLL6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things you could try out:

- Can you hit the Refresh button before you fill in the details? The page will query Azure to detect any newly added services.
  [image]
- You can also try logging out of the qnamaker portal and log in again to check if you are able to select the service.

Hope this helps!

Comment: On Monday, when I was working on this this, I had tried both options a few times without success. But thanks for the suggestions anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I logged back into QnAMaker today, so nearly two days since I created the QnA Service in Step 1, and now I'm able to select the QnA Service in Step 2. Not a great user experience but at least its working now.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue; I am new to azure. I observed that while creating azure QnA service I choose same location as my Resource group. Then it worked.