# QnAMaker bot default directory issue in Azure

Tags: azure, bots, azure-qna-maker, knowledge-management

I cannot see my Azure qnamaker knowledge base in 'All tenants'. I see my default directory under the drop-down but cannot click on it. Can someone help me resolve this?

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61728694/unable-to-select-qna-service-in-the-create-knowledge-base-wizard/61737942#61737942